# 2D k means clustering neural network

Tags: neural-network, k-means

I study atm Neural networks and one question keeps me awake.

Let us assume we have the k means clustering problem in 2D. How would the actual network look like?

I can find only that the updating rule would be something like w_i = w_i + epsilon(x - w_i). That is okay.

Would it work if I do a simple net that looks like that:
I have 2 inputneurons (2D) and each of them has a line to next level neurons, let us assume there are 3 Clusters so 3 neurons in the next layer. So would it work like that?
2 neurons in inputlayer fully connected with 3 neurons in secondlayer... and my w_i would be the connection to the Cluster it belongs from both input neurons.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. After reading the question, I have no idea what you are talking about, are you somehow combining k-means and neural networks? If so, more detail would be needed, but it seems the question is too broad, because neural network design is not really on-topic here. Remember that SO is a question/answer site about programming.

Comment: i think it is a bit offtopic. I wanted to know how I design my neural network for k means clustering. Cuz in University we only got the learning rule, but not how it would look like :D

Comment: The problem is that k-means clustering and neural networks are not generally mixed, so its unclear of what exactly you are talking about.